# Slick not loading picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

https://jonathanrace77.github.io/

In the portfolio section there is a "sync" version of the slick carousel. (The top carousel should show what is selected in the bottom).

However, on a fresh load of the page, the top carousel shows nothing. It is only after the page is refreshed (not hard refreshed), that the picture shows.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: This carousel seems to be working fine for me in Chrome/Mac. The slideshow doesn't work at all in Firefox/Mac...the slides are all just stacked on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider div img did not like width:auto.

Setting this as px or vw (in my case) solved the problem.